# PythonのC拡張モジュール内でUnicodeDecodeErrorが発生する場合の対処方法について

Tags: python

**環境**  
Windows 10 Pro 64bit
Python 3.6.1

pyscardというPCSCのモジュールを使用しています。pyscard内で下記のようなエラーメッセージを取得していうる部分があるのですが、ここでUnicodeDecodeErrorが発生しています。

```
def SCardGetErrorMessage(lErrCode):
    """
    SCardGetErrorMessage(long lErrCode) -> ERRORSTRING *

    Parameters
    ----------
    lErrCode: long



    This function return a human readable text for the given PC/SC error code.

    from smartcard.scard import *
    ...
    hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard, SCARD_PCI_T0, SELECT + DF_TELECOM)
    if hresult != SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
        raise error, 'Failed to transmit: ' + SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult)
    ...

    """
    # UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: invalid start byte
    return _scard.SCardGetErrorMessage(lErrCode)  # <= UnicodeDecodeError
```

恐らくWindows側がCP932に日本語エラーメッセージを返して、エラーが発生しているような気がします。sys.getdefaulencoding()の値は'utf-8'でした。

```
import sys

print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
>> utf-8
```

Windowsのエラーメッセージを英語表記にすることができれば解決できる？そのプロセス内だけ、英語表記に変えれると望ましいのですが。Python側で何か対処方法があれば一番ありがたいです。